# List of maps in custom Hive UDF

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm writing custom UDF and expect an `ARRAY<MAP<STRING, STRING>>` argument. In my `evaluate` method I then do

```
@Override
public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] args) throws HiveException {
    List<?> elements = listObjectInspector.getList(args[0].get());
```

The question is, is `elements` now a list of valid Java maps or do I still have to call `mapObjectInspector.getMap()` for every element in `elements`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is yes. First use `ListObjectInspector` then for each element call `MapObjectInspector` .

Comment: Well, okay. Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: I have not come across on hive wiki. I implemented similar scenario in past. Let me know in case you need a code snippet.